# Adding listeners to my tabs

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

How do I add listeners to my tabs. So what I want to do is, when I click on my tab I want to do something.
Here's the code for the tabs:

```
package app.my.com.wave;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
    spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);
}}
```

Here is my XML folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TabWidget
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="60px"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:text="This is tab1"
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="60px"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:text="This is tab 2"
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="60px"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:text="This is tab 3"
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So in conclusion I want to do something when these  tabs are pressed.Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use setOnTabChangeListener

```
 tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
   @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
   Log.e("Tab number ", "" + tabHost.getCurrentTab());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a callback to be invoked when the selected state of any of the items in this list of tab changes.

```
 mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
   @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
   Log.d("MainActivity", "current tab index :: " + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
  }
```

While setting up tabhost android f/w adds the callback to be invoked while clicking on specific view of tabwidget. After setCurrenttab method with changed tab index, it will in turn invoke the onTabChange call.